# Should I use QCoreApplication::processEvents() or QApplication::processEvents()?

Tags: user-interface, qt

I have a method which is called from both `QThreads` and the main thread.  this method can sometimes take a long time to do its computations in a loop so I put `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` and this prevents the GUI from freezing.  At some point I had changed `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` for `QApplication::processEvents()` but that caused the GUI to freeze (im pretty sure thats what was fereezing it because since I put `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` back it hasnt frozen again)  Am I right to think that calling `QApplication::processEvents()` from both the main thread and QThreads can freeze the GUI?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Neither, processEvent() should be calld only when you have actual pending events to process.
You may find this useful : [How to make Qt work when main thread is busy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386043/how-to-make-qt-work-when-main-thread-is-busy)

Comment: I am going to try QtConcurrent::run.  Can I do GUI operations in there or should I still emit signals like for the case of a QThread

Comment: @yan bellavance: You should emit signals, as it will be in a separate thread.  Or you could use the QFuture stuff to help, which will do a lot of creating and emitting the signals for you.

Answer (score 12):

You'll be much better off moving the long-running process out of the main thread so you don't need to call `processEvents()`.  Within that long-running process, you can emit whatever signals you need so the gui has sufficient information to do updates, etc.  `processEvents`, however, is *usually* a crutch for a poor design.

Comment: I am going to try QtConcurrent::run. Can I do GUI operations in there or should I still emit signals like for the case of a QThread

Comment: Gui operations may only be performed in the main thread. QtConcurrent is a good idea, especially if you can divide your work up to utilize multiple cores.