# Can't change QLabel text twice in a slot

Tags: qt

I have a problem with updating `QLabel` text two times serially in the following function:

```
void MainWindow::on_button_clicked(){ 
   ui->label->setText("Training");
   object->training();
   ui->label->setText("Training finished");
}
```

The first call of `setText()` never changes label's text. What's wrong with this example?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386043/how-to-make-qt-work-when-main-thread-is-busy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This slot call is running on the GUI thread.  And when you get to the end of the function, is when the GUI has a chance to do updates.

You can force an update with:

```
ui->label->update();  // queues up an update event
qApp->processEvents(); // processes the update event

// start some longer code snippet
// ...
```

And also note that `qApp` is short for `QApplication::instance()`.  Include `<QApplication>` to be able to use it.

UPDATE: `QtConcurrent` and `QThread` stuff

But like it says in @Mat's comment and referenced answer... this may be bandaid solution for something that really should be launched in a `QThread` or with a `QFuture` or some other `QtConcurrent` class.  Thread Synchronization and related topics have a learning curve, so be careful when starting it, if you haven't done that before.

I liked how it was done here: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Progress-bar

Hope that helps.