# pyqt5 QPushButton setStyleSheet not updating GUI inside connect function

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qpushbutton, qfiledialog

I am using `pyqt5` to build a basic GUI for a project. The UI has only one button to open a dialog to pick file `Load Data` Button. When we click on this button, a `File Dialog` is opened to select a *.csv or *.tsv file.

I am trying to change the color of this `QPushButton` to **blue** using `setStyleSheet` property when data is being loaded. The button color should  changes to 
**green** when data load is complete.

The button color is not changing to **blue**. It changes to **green** at the end when data is fully loaded. But not to **blue** while  `pd.read_csv('train_v2.csv')` is running. I have even set the `setStyleSheet` property before running `pd.read_csv` line. Here is the code i am working on:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QProgressBar,
    QAction, QPushButton, QFileDialog, QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.btn = QPushButton('Load data', self)
        self.btn.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 30)
        self.btn.move(200, 40)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)
        self.statusBar()
        self.progressbar = QProgressBar()

        openFile = QAction(QIcon('open.png'), 'Open', self)
        openFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openFile.setStatusTip('Open new File')
        openFile.triggered.connect(self.showDialog)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(openFile)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 650, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('File Dialog')
        self.show()

    def showDialog(self):

        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File", '/home',
        "Tabular (*csv *.tsv)")

        if fname[0] is not '':

            self.btn.setStyleSheet(" background-color: blue")
            data = pd.read_csv(fname[0])

            self.setStatusTip('!!! Data loaded sucessfully!!! Data contains: %d rows and %d columns.' % (data.shape[0], data.shape[1]))

            self.btn.setStyleSheet(" background-color: green")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am using python 3.4.5 with pyqt5 installed in it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386043/how-to-make-qt-work-when-main-thread-is-busy

Comment: I'd try `background-color: rgb(0,255,0);` because "blue" might not be a supported word, while "green" maybe it's. Check this way and see if it works.

Comment: If you still need it try to make another question not duplicated and I'll answer it to you with a small example, since this one I'm not able to post an answer. Just tag me or send here the link of the other question.