# Temporarily disable window during a function call

Tags: c++, qt, qtconcurrent

Consider:

```
class Worker
{
public:
  void DoWork();
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

private:
  Worker MyWorker;

public:
  void DoWork();
};
```

I want the `DoWork` function of my `MainWindow` to behave like:

```
void MainWindow::DoWork()
{
  setEnabled(false);

  std::future<void> Resu = std::async(std::launch::async, &Worker::DoWork, &MyWorker);

  while (Resu.wait_for(100ms) == std::future_status::timeout)
    qApp->processEvents();

  try
    { Resu.get(); }
  catch (Except const &MyExcept)
    { QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", MyExcept.What()); }

   setEnabled(true);
 }
```

This works as I want: (i) the window is disabled while doing the work,
 (ii) the window stays responsive while doing the work (can be moved and resized), and (iii) any
 `Except` thrown in `Worker::DoWork` is caught conveniently.

However, this solution relies upon `std::future` and `qApp->processEvents()`, the latter
not being recommended by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1386160).

How can I write the above code properly in Qt?

So far, I have tried:

```
void MainWindow::DoWork()
{
  setEnabled(false);

  QFuture<void> Resu = QtConcurrent::run(std::bind(&Worker::DoWork, &MyWorker));

  try
    { while (Resu.isRunning()) qApp->processEvents(); }
  catch (Except const &MyExcept)
    { QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", MyExcept.What()); }

   setEnabled(true);
 }
```

and I found the drawbacks of consuming a whole thread (because the too frequent calls to `qApp->processEvents()`), and furthermore the exceptions are not properly caught.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`QFutureWatcher`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuturewatcher.html) to receive notification about the completion of your `QFuture` without the need to be busy-waiting calling `processEvents`.

Basically you subscribe to the signal `QFutureWatcher<void>::finished` to know when the operation is complete.  In the associated slot you re-enable the widget.  Particularly important is to call `future.waitForFinished()` even if the computation is already complete, to force the transfer of any QException that was thrown in the worker thread see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qexception.html).  It looks like a workaround but I don't know if there is a better solution for this.

After the subscription you call `setFuture()` function to start your `doWork` operation.  The computation will be carried out in its own thread.

In this way you should be able to do everything as you want:

1. the window is disabled while doing the work
2. the window stays responsive while doing the work (can be moved and resized)
3. any `QException` thrown in `Worker::doWork` is caught conveniently

Here is a minimal working example, based on your question.  It should show you what I mean...

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QException>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QThread>
#include <QtConcurrent>


class Exception : public QException
{
public:
    Exception(const QString& message = "") : m_message {message} { }

    void raise() const override { throw *this; }

    Exception *clone() const override { return new Exception(*this); }

    QString message() { return m_message; }

private:
    QString m_message;
};


class Worker
{
public:
    void doWork() {
        QThread::sleep(5);
        // throw Exception {"something bad happened..."};
        QThread::sleep(5);
    }
};


class Button : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Button(QWidget* parent = nullptr) : QPushButton {parent} {
        resize(400, 300);
        setText("Click me to wait!");

        connect(this, &QPushButton::clicked,
                this, &Button::doWork);
    }

public slots:
    void doWork() {
        setEnabled(false);

        auto future {QtConcurrent::run(&m_worker, &Worker::doWork)};

        auto watcher {new QFutureWatcher<void> {}};
        connect(watcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::finished,
                [=]() mutable {
                    try {
                        // Call this to force the transfer of any QException that was thrown in the worker thread
                        // (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qexception.html)
                        future.waitForFinished();
                    } catch (Exception& e) {
                        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", e.message());
                    }
                    setEnabled(true);
                });

        watcher->setFuture(future);
    }

private:
    Worker                  m_worker;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app {argc, argv};

    auto button {new Button {}};
    button->show();

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: The restriction that the exception must inherit from `QException` is kinda limiting in my case. Anyway, now it's perfectly clear to me what the correct way of doing so in Qt is.

Comment: I completely agree with you. I also think this is a limitation in some cases.  Maybe there are better ways to manage this, but I was not able to find them =)