# PyQt5: QMainWindow freezes when calling a long running function

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Creating a QMainWindow >> pushing start button >> that connects a long-running function with a QLabel as arg >> updating the label while running the long function.

I want to update the status of the long-running function in the GUI. But as soon as the long-running function starts the whole window freezes

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QLabel,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)

def runLongTask(label):
    label.setText('<1> sleeping for 10s ...')
    time.sleep(10)
    label.setText('<2> sleeping for 10s ...')
    time.sleep(10)
    label.setText('End')

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("GUI freeze FIX")
        self.resize(350, 250)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label.setText('No Update')
        countBtn = QPushButton("Start")
        countBtn.clicked.connect(lambda: runLongTask(self.label))
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(countBtn)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(layout)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use PyQt5's threads to start your long function in a different thread. That way, the main UI thread won't be busy itself, and will even be able to receive signals from the other thread and therefore update the UI.

[This article](https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/) is a good introduction to QThread usage.

Here is an example of a long task executed when clicking a button. The long task uses dummy `time.sleep(x)` to make it long, but notice how the `update_ui` function is passed, like a callback, to update the UI.

```py
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QProgressBar,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)


def long_running_function(update_ui):
    # Doing something
    time.sleep(1)
    update_ui(percent=25)

    # Doing something else
    time.sleep(1)
    update_ui(percent=50)

    # Another long thing
    time.sleep(1)
    update_ui(percent=75)

    # Almost done
    time.sleep(1)
    update_ui(percent=100)


class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        # Here we pass the update_progress (uncalled!)
        # function to the long_running_function:
        long_running_function(self.update_progress)
        self.finished.emit()

    def update_progress(self, percent):
        self.progress.emit(percent)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.progress = QProgressBar()
        self.button = QPushButton("Start")
        layout.addWidget(self.progress)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.execute)

        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)
        self.show()

    def execute(self):
        self.update_progress(0)
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)

        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.worker.progress.connect(self.update_progress)

        self.thread.start()
        self.button.setEnabled(False)

    def update_progress(self, progress):
        self.progress.setValue(progress)
        self.button.setEnabled(progress == 100)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. One typo, in update_ui(progress=25) it should be percent in place of progress.

Comment: @imankalyan If that answer was correct, [could you accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You may manually call processEvents:

```
def runLongTask(label):
    label.setText('<1> sleeping for 10s ...')
    QApplication.processEvents()
    time.sleep(10)
    label.setText('<2> sleeping for 10s ...')
    QApplication.processEvents()
    time.sleep(10)
    label.setText('End')
    label.update()
```

For more info, you should search for "qt Keeping the GUI Responsive",
or the QThread/QtConcurrent answer here: [How to make Qt work when main thread is busy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386043/how-to-make-qt-work-when-main-thread-is-busy)

Comment: No. processEvents should only be used in specific situations that potentially allow minimal event queue processing or *actually* require "clearing" the queue. With blocks that take *this* much time (10 seconds is a lot) this is *not* a good choice, most importantly because it could cause lots of issue in input interaction.

Comment: Though it's updating the label, the GUI still freezes while sleeping.